# Cypress assertions fails on OpenShift pod but passes on local machine

Tags: server, automation, openshift, devops, cypress

I have a server that runs cypress projects on OpenShift for multiple applications. It manages to run test specs with no issues, but recently a peculiar issue happened with the test specs for one application.

In this application, each spec has a `beforeEach` method which performs the following:

```js
cy.visit('/', { failOnStatusCode: false })
cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.config().baseUrl + '/')
```

I know this assertion is very redundant and it doesn't make much sense, but these are the specs we got from one of the applications.

When we run this spec locally, the assertion passes without any issue. When we run this spec on the server, we get the following error (I changed the application URL for the sake of this example):

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying: expected 'https://www.google.com/'
to equal 'https://www.google.com//`
```

As you can see, the assertion fails because of the additional `/` that's somehow added to the assertion. This is strange, as this exact assertion passes locally, but not on the server. Any ideas why?

`baseUrl` value is `https://www.google.com`

I'm using Cypress 6.0.0

Comment: instead of exactly matching the url with `eq`, you can use contain `cy.url().should('contain', Cypress.config().baseUrl + '/')`. With contain you can have more than the desired text and still match.

Comment: @AlapanDas We are not the ones who write the tests, we just run them on our server. It works if we run it locally but not on our server. The taste are written by our clients.